# How to test unexported struct field in a different package in go?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I have a package that creates objects with a factory. The structs have unexported fields, e.g.:

```
package fetcher
type GitFetcher struct {
    uri    string
}
```

I have another package that parses some config files and then builds another object which uses the above objects:

```
package config
type Source struct {
    fetcher    GitFetcher
}
```

I'm trying to test my `config` package. I want to build some expected objects, but since my tests are in `config` and my `GitFetcher` is in `fetcher` I can't just create the objects I want, e.g.:

```
package config
expected := GitFetcher{
    uri: "example.com/repo.git"      // doesn't work. Field isn't exported.
}
```

How can I build objects across packages for testing like this? I don't want to use the `fetcher` factory method since the parameters it takes aren't straightforward.

Comment: Down-voted for not knowing go. Nice :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to test unexported [...] a different package in go?

Not at all. Undoable, do not try.

(If the unexported thing has an exported method, then you can call this method.)

Comment: @leafbebop Unexported does not mean you cannot have an instance of such a type. If some function F in package a gives you a a.unexported with method M and thne you can do u := a.F(); u.M().

Comment: I thought you were referring to an unexported field as OP specified. Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to achieve this. You have multiple options to achieve something similar, all with their own tradeoffs. It's up to you to decide which tradeoff is most acceptable in your case.

In general, I would try them in this order:

1. Make package `config` depend on an interface instead of on the `GitFetcher` struct. That way you can mock `GitFetcher` in your tests.
2. Add an additional factory method specifically for tests that can construct `GitFetcher` more easily.
3. Make the unexported field exported.
4. Simply combine the packages. That way you can access the unexported fields of both objects in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible to test a struct with unexported fields.

It's cludgy, but you can use `fmt.Sprint()`.

```
func isExpectedStruct(myStruct *otherPak.MyStruct) bool {
    expectedStr := "&{1 2}"
    str := fmt.Sprint(myStruct)

    return expectedStr == str
}
```

OR

if you only want to test one specific field

```
func isExpectedField(myStruct *otherPak.MyStruct) bool {
    expectedSubStr := "unexportedField:2"
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", myStruct)
    return strings.Contains(str, expectedSubStr)
}
```

But just because you can doesn't mean you should.

I think in most cases it would be better to change the field to exported, or use mocking, but if those aren't options for some reason this gives you another option.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many properties you need to test, then one (hacky?) way is to create a getter function for that property.

For example, create something like this in the package:

```
func (g *gitFetcher) GetUri() string {
    return g.uri
}
```

and in your mock, you can have

```
type GitFetcherMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (g *GitFetcherMock) GetUri() string {
    args := g.Called()
    return args.Get(0)
}
```

and you can pass in GetUri() wherever you would have used the actual URI in the actual code.